# Get Existing Item Specifics from eBay API

Tags: c#, sdk, ebay-api

I am using eBay API to list new / update existing product using C#. I need to know a way to get Item Specifics for an Item so that when I update the product, the specifics are not lost.

I am using `DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll` with `GetSellerListCall()` to bring down all details. What I understand from the [documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/DetailLevelCodeType.html), if I use `DetailLevelCodeType.ItemReturnAttributes` using the `GetItem()` call, I can get the same.

My question is if we have any way to get all data including Item Specifics using the `GetSellerList()` call?

Below is the sample code I am using -

```
 GetSellerListCall call = new GetSellerListCall(_context);
        call.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
        call.Pagination = new PaginationType() { EntriesPerPage = 20 };
        call.EndTimeFrom = DateTime.UtcNow;
        call.EndTimeTo = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);

        do
        {
            call.Pagination.PageNumber++;

            ItemTypeCollection items = call.GetSellerList();

            foreach (ItemType item in items)
            {
                //Perform My Action
            }
        }
        while (call.HasMoreItems);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any solution with the `GetSellerListCall()` and hence moved on by making an extra call to `GetItem()` using the sample below. Hope this helps.

```
GetItemCall call = new GetItemCall(_context);
call.IncludeItemSpecifics = true;
call.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ItemReturnAttributes);

ItemType _itemSpecific = call.GetItem('Item ID from eBay');
```

Comment: For Java SDK: `GetItemCall.setIncludeItemSpecifics(true);` before calling `GetItemCall.getItem(itemIDStr);` [I was here looking for a solution for Java SDK, so it might help others.]